# Double array in php and javascript issue

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I need to create an array in php and then to assign to java script function.I need something like this
 I need this array as same as it looks

```
$users = array(
array('username' => 'user1', 'email' => 'user1@your-host.com'),
array('username' => 'user2', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
array('username' => 'user3', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
...
);
```

For $users array i tried this code

```
 $users = array();
while($rw = $objApp->dbrow($res))
{
 $users []=array('username'=>$rw['username'],
      'email'=>$rw['email']
);
}
```

Is this OK?

If yes then i want to pass the same array to javascript function...here is what i tried

```
  objJS::importUsers( <?php echo json_encode($results) ?>);
```

This is simple,what is the issue in my code due to which it is not working

Comment: what is `objJS::importUsers`

Comment: objJS::importUsers( <?php echo json_encode($results) ?>); this line is wrong in any way .

Comment: Indeed, the asker is not showing any javascript...

Comment: Have your problem be solved? If not try to use my code, I have tested.

Comment: Not solved yet...can not create json as i need in my question

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass arbitrary object or array from PHP to Javascript, you may want to try JSON. (untested)

```
<?php
    $data = array('whatever');
    $json = json_encode($data);
?>

<script>
    var json = '<?=$json?>';
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);

    // do with your obj.
</script>
```

[PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[Javascript JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Note that it only works if your object/array does not contain any key/values containing the `'` character.

---

**EDIT**: It appears that you could have mixed up syntaxes.

Javascript has no `::` operator.

I believe that

```
objJS::importUsers( <?php echo json_encode($results) ?>);
```

should actually be

```
objJS.importUsers( <?php echo json_encode($results) ?>);
```

However, as you don't tell us what `objJs::importUsers` is, we can just wild guessing. Is it a Javascript function, or a PHP class method, or something else?

If it is a PHP function, I wonder why you would need to pass it to Javascript - just call that method directly!

**EDIT** So I read the comment from other post here, you want to pass a PHP `array` to Javascript and appears as an Javascript `array`. Unfortunately they are not the same. Javascript `array` keys cannot really be strings (like `'email'`), they are actually Javascript `objects`

Comment: Keep in mind that this does NOT allow interoperability between PHP and JS

Comment: Should that php <?=> tag be wrapped in quotes?

Comment: I do wrap `<?=?>` in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $result =['your entire array']
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

In your javascript!!!

```
var JS_ARRAY=[];
$.ajax({
            url: "../xyz/xyz.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {//your data to be send},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(data)
                     JS_ARRAY.push(JSON.stringify(data));
}
});
//use this JS_ARRAY in you js function.
```

Comment: @Methew:you are making your task difficult by adding   objJS::importUsers( <?php echo json_encode($results) ?>);......There is no need to do such thing..your data will reach the js function in a format given by json encode.You can then parse it the way you want.Did you try this code??

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $users = array(
        array('username' => 'user1', 'email' => 'user1@your-host.com'),
        array('username' => 'user2', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
        array('username' => 'user3', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
    );
    $users_json_str = json_encode($users);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // here is you java script
    // the variable users is the same with the $users in your php code
    var users = <?php echo "$users_json_str";?>;

    // you can access the first username
    var first_user_name = users[0]['username'];
    </script>
```

Comment: It still now working...here is what i got...var json = '[{"username":"admin","email":"abc@gmail.com"},{"username":"ahmed.a","email":"ggg@abc.ae"}]'; SPC.userPrefs =$.parseJSON(json);

Comment: It looks like as code..i need to view as SPC.userPrefs = $.parseJSON('my user array');

Comment: `var json = '[{"username":"admin","email":"abc@gmail.com"},{"username":"ahmed.a","email":"gg‌​g@abc.ae"}]'` is the `$users` variable assigned in php.

Comment: My question i very simple,i need $users array as same as i shown in my question..and then i want to pass this array to javascript function...how to do this?

Comment: :My 90% problem is solved.can you please only tell me that the user array i am creating in while loop is ok?How to develop array like  $users = array(
        array('username' => 'user1', 'email' => 'user1@your-host.com'),
        array('username' => 'user2', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
        array('username' => 'user3', 'email' => 'user2@your-host.com'),
    );

Comment: The way you developed the `$user` array is correct. This is just the way we develop it.